# Insert values at different index points in a list

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a start list:

```
start_list = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 14, 20]
```

I now choose to remove/delete three items from this list at positions:

```
remove_list = [0, 3, 5]
```

With Numpy this can be done with:

```
>> final_list = np.delete(start_list, remove_list, axis=0)
[2, 3, 6, 11, 14, 20]
```

Now I wish to go back to have the original structure of the `start_list` but with different values of course than then ones removed, i.e. something like this:

```
new_list = [0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0, 11, 14, 20]
```

So the index removed, have now been restored into the same arrangement as the beginning, but with the values removed now replaced with zeros.

If I use something like `numpy.insert(final_list, remove_list, 0)` I get a new list, with zeros inserted at the index positions in `remove_list`. However, that is relative to the `final_list` indexes, so it ends up with:

```
new_list = [0, 2, 3, 6, 0, 11, 14, 0, 20]
```

Which is obviously not the same as the `start_list`.

If I iterate like:

```
new_final_list = [np.insert(final_list, k, 0) for k in remove_list]
```

I just end up with three arrays, where one zero has been inserted into the indexes from `remove_list` in each.

So basically, I just wanna "re-create" the `start_list` from the `final_list` but with zeros in the positions of the values that were removed.

Comment: Why not directly do `np.put(start_list, remove_list, 0)`. Why intermediate step?

Comment: You are mixing up lists and arrays.  `numpy` `delete` and `insert` are inefficient compared to equivalent operations on a list.  If you really are starting with a list, stick with the list (unless you are doing things that clearly work better with arrays).

Comment: Do you need the intermediate state?

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
new_list = [x if i not in remove_list else 0 for i, x in enumerate(start_list)]
print(new_list)
#[0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0, 11, 14, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [453]: start_list = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 14, 20]
In [454]: remove_list = [0, 3, 5]
```

If we make an array from `start_list`, it is easy to replace selected items with new value such as 0.  Delete and re insert is the hard way:

```
In [455]: arr = np.array(start_list)
In [456]: arr[remove_list] = 0
In [457]: arr
Out[457]: array([ 0,  2,  3,  0,  6,  0, 11, 14, 20])
```

Removing items from the list is easy, with a list comprehension.  This is a variant on @pault's replace comprehension:

```
In [458]: [x for i,x in enumerate(start_list) if i not in remove_list]
Out[458]: [2, 3, 6, 11, 14, 20]
```

`np.delete` is ok for removing items from an array (or list turned into an array), but internally it is complicated (because of its generality).  I think in a case like this it just uses a boolean mask:

```
In [459]: mask = np.ones(len(start_list), bool)
In [460]: mask[remove_list] = False
In [461]: mask
Out[461]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])
In [462]: arr[mask]
Out[462]: array([ 2,  3,  6, 11, 14, 20])
```

Timing wise, if you start with a list, it will be faster to stick with lists.  Creating arrays has an overhead, and operations like can't over come that.

Elements can be removed from lists with slicing - in-place

```
In [464]: for i in remove_list[::-1]:
     ...:     start_list[i:i+1] = []
     ...:     
In [465]: start_list
Out[465]: [2, 3, 6, 11, 14, 20]
```

But we have to start from the end of `remove_list` to avoid messing up the count.  This a relatively well known Python list idiom.

We could insert elements into a list in the same way, but we have to adjust the indexing to work with the intermediate size.

```
In [483]: insert_list = [i-j for i,j in zip(remove_list,range(3))]
In [484]: start_list=[2,3,6,11,14,20]
In [485]: for i in insert_list[::-1]:
     ...:     start_list[i:i] = [0]
     ...:     
     ...:     
In [486]: start_list
Out[486]: [0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0, 11, 14, 20]
```

I came up with `insert_list` by a bit of trial-and-error and working back from the desired result.

Comment: This seems to be able to do the trick, however, only when the remove_list and start_list are sorted. If it is random, or something similar, it doesn't seem to give the correct list in the end. And that is unfortunately how it is in my case, and I can't sort the lists due to different stuff.

Comment: It's still possible to work with lists when the remove list isn't sorted, but you just have to be more careful/pedantic/clever when adjusting from items that have already been removed or inserted.  The principle is still the same, it's just the details that differ.